# What happen between `printf` and `fputc` on STM32?

Tags: c, printf, stm32

Suppose I am using a Nucleo board with a STM32L476RG processor.
I'm compiling with Uvision5 a basic code which is doing the following:

```
int main( void )
{
    printf( "Started\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

It appears that the `printf` is actually sending the `"Started\n"` string on UART to the ST-link of the Nucleo, which then encapsulate the data on USB. I can then receive the data on any kind of Serial Sniffer tool.

To do this properly, I had to do define the following function (plus other GPIO and Device settings that are out of topic for the moment, but that makes the following working):

```
int fputc( int ch, FILE *f )
{
    HAL_UART_Transmit( &UartHandle, ( uint8_t * )&ch, 1, 0xFFFF );
    return ch;
}
```

So far so good. I'm ok with that. However, I can't find anywhere what's happening to `printf` so that at some point `fputc` is called. I did start such a program using a debugger, it shows that the `printf` is actually called `__0printf$5`, which might be a compiled function calling a `_printf_core`. This last function is calling the newly defined `fputc`.

Where are defined all this call stack? Note that I don't plan to modify it, I'm just curious as I use a lot this functionality, but I still don't clearly understand *why* it is working...

Comment: `glibc` is open source, you can read the code.

Comment: `printf()` puts the formatted result in a buffer, then it calls `fputc()` in a loop on the buffer.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks, I haven't even think about glibc... ^^

Comment: Actually it quite useless knowledge unless you are not going to modify the vprintf.... functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that work for me, From ST Community:

https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkfAsSAJ/stm32cubemx-stm32f407-discovery-printf-doesnt-work

```
int _write( int file, char *ptr, int len ){
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,(uint8_t*)&ptr[i],1,10);
    }
    char ch='\r';
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,(uint8_t*)&ch,1,10);
}
```